# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Auto redirecting to https for rails app in EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2

I tried so hard to make it here and at the final step in deploying rails app to EC2 the http request is auto redirected to https and i am getting **This webpage is not available** error.

I also ran a temporary test rails app in production and it works fine(just plain http and no redirects here).

I also commented

```
# config.force_ssl = true
```

the above line in production.rb and restarted the **nginx** server.

Configuration i am running Passenger on top of nginx and Postgres on Ubuntu.

I am suspecting the culprit is rails. Any suggestions or help? Or correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

**EDIT**

Strangely it works well on Safari and Firefox. But only Chrome is redirecting to https and hence the **webpage not available error**

Comment: You found solution?

Comment: @AdrianoResende Yeah i solved it but can't able to recall now how i did it. I should have updated it here when i did that. Will update you once i found the solution.